# How to follow a link via swipe in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, swipe

To handle swiping I use the script posted here:
http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/

It works fine.

Now instead of changing the background (what the original script does), I would like it to grab the link contained within an `<a>` which has a class, and which is normally a link to the next page, but for mouse events like so:

```
<a href="mypage02.html" target="_self" class="NextP" title="My Second Page">
```

and then load the page.

I  have many pages, with the same structure, I don't want to manually define the links. I want the js to get hold of the current `href` contained in the `<a>` and launch it, when triggered by the swipe. If possible.

Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to look for a

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="NextP">
```

element in a page (an `<a>` anchor tag with a `NextP` class), and when the user swipes, visit that link.

To do this, I would

1. look through your HTML for an `a.NextP` element, and capture its `href` attribute.
2. when the user swipes, set `window.location.href` to this attribute.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var nextPageUrl = document.querySelector('a.NextP').href;
  
  // just guessing how swiping works, I haven't looked through your library
  document.body.onswiperight = function(){
    window.location.href = nextPageUrl;
  };
};
```

Of course, you would use the correct method of detecting the swipe.